# HTML5 object fit window height

Tags: javascript, css, html

Using AdminLTE.

```
<object id="topo" data="http://www.web-source.net" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" style="min-height: 100%;"><p>This is the fallback code!</p></object>
```

The above code stretches the object width but not the height, the height is as small as possible.

How can I make it the same height as the window?

Comment: What's the height of the container element? Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: I don't know how to work a fiddle with <object> it doesn't work on it.

Comment: you can get window height with`height:100vh;` css property

Comment: @Kejt hey, yeah! 100vh kind of works, almost there. Still a little out of sync for some reason, it's a little bigger than the window itself, probably because of the header and whatnot.

Comment: awesome! you can position your header to floating over your object or you can calculate needed height `calc(100vh - 80px);`

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for @Kejt THANK YOU, answer below and I'll award you.

Comment: lovely! thank you @Rosenberg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css property `height: calc(100vh-100px)` where 100px is your header height for example

Answer (score 1):

create a container with the following [CSS Viewport Units: vw, vh, vmin and vmax](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css-viewport-units/) then you can use percentage to control DOM elements with `display:block` property:

```css
.container {
  height: 90vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

object {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  height: 80%;
}

object > p {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <object id="topo" data="http://www.web-source.net" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" style="min-height: 100%;">
    <p>This is the fallback code!</p>
  </object>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eapo/ba2cnc9r/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, the issue is on the default body margin, set the body's margin to 0:

```
body{margin: 0px;}
```

Comment: I have that set already, `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px; }`

Comment: So I must've misunderstood, using your code given, it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this:

```
body{min-height: 100vh;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the style below:

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;}
```